# geopath overlap after scale D3.js

Tags: javascript, svg, d3.js, geojson

[This the geojson that I am using](https://gist.github.com/RajuBhosale/a136cf7b0d437067bdb1/raw/33c9d96c70931f56883b9f50a3dd3f63f605938a/map.geojson)

My code is

```
var width = d3.round($('.map-container').width());
var height =d3.round($(window).height()); 
var svg = d3.select("#india")
            .append("svg")
            .attr("width", width)
            .attr("height", height);
//using geojson file mentioned above just name and extension changed
d3.json("/Scripts/in-states.js", function (json) {
    var center = d3.geo.centroid(json)
    var scale = 1000;
    var offset = [width / 2, height / 2];
    var projection = d3.geo.mercator()
                           .scale(scale)
                           .center(center)
                           .translate(offset);


    var path = d3.geo.path().projection(projection);

      svg.selectAll("path")
                .data(json.features)
                .enter()
                .append("path")
                .attr("class", function (d) {
                    return "state " + d.properties.name;
                })
                .attr("stroke-width", "0.2em")
                .attr("fill",'#045A8D')
                .attr("d", path);
    });
```

Now when this gets render, feature where name='Lakshadweep' covers the whole map.

[here is the example](http://rajubhosale.github.io/visualization/fiddle.html)!

I couldn't find out why is that happening? coz the above mentioned geojson works as expected in gist.
Does the sequence of paths(states) matters in this case? (I am kinda new to svg and d3)

Comment: It looks like that particular path might be inverted. You could try loading this into a GIS program and then exporting as GeoJSON again to normalize.

Comment: @LarsKotthoff thanks for a clue.solved.

Comment: Great, I'll add that as an answer for reference.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like that particular path might be inverted. You could try loading this into a GIS program (such as [QGIS](http://qgis.org/en/site/)) and then exporting as GeoJSON again to normalize.

Comment: I missed to read following note in [documentation](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Geo-Paths) Important: the inside of a polygon is all points that the polygon winds around in a clockwise order. If your GeoJSON input has polygons in the wrong winding order, you must reverse them, say via ST_ForceRHR; you can also convert your GeoJSON to TopoJSON, and this will happen automatically.